# CProgressCtrl::CprogressCtrl(const CProgressCtrl &)"(declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am working on an MFC dialog application. I created a progress control (`IDC_PROGRESSUPLOADING`) in the dialog interface and add a variable `m_progress` for this control. The `m_progress` is passed to a function (`start_update`), which will set and display the progress control.

Dlg.h

```
...
public:
    afx_msg void OnStnClickedStaticFileName();
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeEditFilePath();
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButtonSelectFile();
    afx_msg void OnStnClickedStaticFilePath();
    CString m_filepath;
    CProgressCtrl m_progress;
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedButtonStartUpdate();
...
```

Dlg.cpp

```
int start_update(CString path, CProgressCtrl progress) {
...
}
...
void CDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_FILE_PATH, m_filepath);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_PROGRESSUPLOADING, m_progress);
}
...
void CDlg::OnBnClickedButtonStartUpdate()
{
    start_update(m_filepath, m_progress);
}
...
```

But Visual Studio tells me that there is an error:
[image]

> CProgressCtrl::CprogressCtrl(const CProgressCtrl &)"(declared
> implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Can you please help to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the declaration of `start_update`.  What are the parameters types?  Are you passing the `CProgressCtrl` by value?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Great thanks for your comments. I added declartion in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just focusing on the error, basically a compiler error of this type:

```
SomeObject::SomeObject(const SomeObject &)"(declared implicitly) 
                              cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

indicates that `SomeObject` cannot be copied due to the default compiler's copy  constructor:

`SomeObject::SomeObject(const SomeObject &)`

is unavailable.

The copy constructor can be made unavailable by either

1. Deriving from a class with an unavailable copy constructor.
2. Declaring a copy constructor with the `deleted` specifier.
3. Declaring an unimplemented user-defined copy constructor.

---

The reason why the error happens in this declaration:

`int start_update(CString path, CProgressCtrl progress)`

is that you are passing `CProgressCtrl` by value.  Passing by-value means that a copy is going to be made of the object.  Since copying has been turned off, you get the error message.

The way to get around this is to either pass by reference:

`int start_update(CString path, CProgressCtrl& progress)`

or leave the declaration alone and provide a user-defined copy constructor.

I would think that simply passing by reference would be enough *to get passed the compiler error*.  But again, will this update the progress bar -- that's another story.

Comment: *But again, will this update the progress bar* Why wouldn't it? Passing by value (if allowed) probably wouldn't, as it would update the copy.

Comment: @AdrianMole Just a warning that this fixes the compiler error.  What happens when the program runs, I don't want the questions and answers to snowball into more questions.  Plus, I am no MFC guru.

Comment: Fair enough. But passing by reference is the 'normal' way to send MFC controls to member functions, as in the call to `DDX_Control` (takes a `CWnd&` third argument).

Answer (score 2):

Your `start_update()` function takes its arguments *by value*. So, when you call that, the compiler needs to make copies of the two arguments – and you can't copy a `CProgressCtrl` object.

Probably, the easiest way round this is to make the second argument to `start_update()` a *reference* (and also the first, `CString`, argument, too, would likely do no harm):

```c
int start_update(CString& path, CProgressCtrl& progress) { // Pass args BY REFERENCE
    //...
}
```